# How do I combine the use of pd.groupby and IF condition to return a specific value attached to each unique variable after grouping?

Tags: if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements, duplicates

Please see the simplified tables for me to explain my question and desired outcome.

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ00W.png)

[DESIRED RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44COv.png)

BEFORE:
| Reference ID| Type |
| -------- | -------- |
|LDN-24523|primary|
|LDN-24523|secondary|
|LDN-24523|primary|
|LDN-24523|primary|
|LDN-84558|primary|
|LDN-84558|primary|
|LDN-84558|primary|
|LDN-54535|primary|
|LDN-54535|primary|
|LDN-54535|primary|
|LDN-54535|secondary|
|LDN-98239|primary|
|LDN-98239|primary|
|LDN-98239|primary|
|LDN-39544|primary|
|LDN-39544|secondary|
|LDN-39544|primary|
|LDN-15550|primary|
|LDN-15550|primary|
|LDN-15550|primary|
|LDN-15550|primary|
|LDN-24556|secondary|
|LDN-24556|primary|
|LDN-24556|primary|
|LDN-75921|primary|
|LDN-75921|primary|
|LDN-75921|primary|

DESIRED RESULTS:
| Reference ID| Type |
| -------- | -------- |
|LDN-24523|secondary|
|LDN-84558|primary|
|LDN-54535|secondary|
|LDN-98239|primary|
|LDN-39544|secondary|
|LDN-15550|primary|
|LDN-24556|secondary|
|LDN-75921|primary|

I am trying to group duplicated Reference ID into one row each whilst applying a condition where if there is "secondary" in the 'Type' column, the unique Reference ID after grouping will be attached with "secondary". Or else, if each Reference ID duplicates only have "primary" under "Type" column next to them, it will only return "primary" after grouping for each unique Reference ID.

Can I use pd.groupby + IF condition to achieve this?

I tried using pd.group_by with lambda conditions but resulted in syntax error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an implicit ranking of `primary` and `secondary` which should be made explicit and encoded to numerical values, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'type': ['primary', 'secondary'], 'value': [1, 2]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

gives

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| primary | 1 |
| secondary | 2 |

Join this to the original table

```py
original_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'reference_id': ['LDN-24523', 'LDN-24523', 'LDN-84558', 'LDN-84558'], 
     'type': ['primary', 'secondary', 'primary', 'primary']}
)

original_df \ 
  .merge(d) \ 
  .groupby('referenced_id')['type'] \
  .max() \
  .reset_index()
```

gives

| reference_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| LDN-24523 | secondary |
| LDN-84558 | primary |